# NINA-B30 series registers pdf

Tags: register, documentation

I want to know the register map/registers of the NINA-B30 series ICs, as I am used to writing low-level drivers on MCUs.

I could not find the datasheet that lists all the registers and their function on [u-blox's  website](https://www.u-blox.com/en/product/nina-b30-series-open-cpu-0?legacy=Current).

Do you know where can I find the register map and their descriptions/functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I figured it out. The NINA-B30 is the product's name and not the actual IC inside the product.

Based on [this datasheet](https://content.u-blox.com/sites/default/files/documents/NINA-B30_ProductSummary_UBX-17052930.pdf) the IC inside is the nRF52840, and [this](https://infocenter.nordicsemi.com/pdf/nRF52840_PS_v1.1.pdf) is the datasheet with the registers.

I think uBlox should put the pdf of the nRF52840 in their website so people can check it out faster, OR not trying to figure out a fancy name for their product that has nothing to do with the IC inside of it.